# SQL CSV Import Issue

Tags: sql, google-cloud-sql

I have a few SQL instances on the Cloud platform where we house a large amount of marketing analytics data. We have been manually importing CSV files daily into our instances in order to update daily figures, but as of yesterday, this import has no longer been functioning. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klpEc.png)

The error message is pretty generic and doesn't give any specific error. Is this a known issue at this time? This issue is occurring in both instances that we have, so it seems doubtful its a DB related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Import/Export section of the Diagnosing issues page, in the CloudSQL [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#import-export)? And also the [Issues with importing and exporting data](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/known-issues#import-export), from the same docs. You might get some pointers there.

Comment: Can you also share the exact time when your issue started and the type of instances you use? (MySQL or PostgreSQL)